# How can I position a div right of another div, but have it not take up space?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of items (call them topics), and I want a div to appear so the user can interact with it (call it a topic card) when one hovers over the topic. My current idea is to have a div positioned beside each topic  and position it accordingly. However, I am having trouble doing so. It cannot take up space on the page, so I figure I will be using position:absolute. However, it needs to always be positioned to the right of the topic, and a combination of float:left and position:absolute means the topic card is simply placed to overlap the topic.

Can I get any suggestions on this? I am also open to some kind of jquery suggestion. Really, I will whatever is easiest and most standards-compliant.

Comment: Ninja edit: This may be what you're looking for. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "display" property. Try "display: inline"
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Wow, great! Nice and simple, and sticking to CSS. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you can display at most one set of topicdetails at a time, have one div set to position 0,0 with `display`=`none`. Whenever you need it to show, set the location appropriately (get it from the mousover/hover DOM element, or whatever you use to trigger the event that displays it), and load/set the content. On remove, just set the display to none (you can ignore the content since it will be replace by new content next time it appears).

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of jQuery tooltip plugins out there, you should use one of them and configure it the way you want.

Here are some as example:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 0):

If you know how big everything is then you can absolutely position your "topic card" with a negative `right` to push it off to the side. Something like this CSS:

```
#element {
    margin-right: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
#sidecar {
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: 0;
}
```

And this HTML structure:

```
<div id="element">
    <div id="sidecar">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this to activate it:

```
$('#element').hover(function() {
    $('#sidecar').toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5a79g/

If you don't know how big things are then you can compute the positions and widths using the jQuery [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) methods.